# Не прогружаются слайды в slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

В общем у меня есть слайдер, и когда заходишь, то место слайдов просто белое полотно, при этом, при обновлении страницы всё нормально. Использую slick slider. Я про слайдер с классом(.questContentPhotos__Slider).

```
$('.questContentPhotos__Radios').slick({
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  variableWidth: true,
  asNavFor: '.questContentPhotos__Slider',
  focusOnSelect: true 
});

$('.questContentPhotos__Slider').slick({
  dots : false,
  arrows: true,
  slidesToScroll:1,
  slidesToShow:1,
  infinite:true,
  swipe:true,
  asNavFor: '.questContentPhotos__Radios',
});
```

[Ссылка на страницу](https://vashkaweb.ru/work/quest1/quest.html)

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: flex убери и проверь

Comment: Спасибо, я уже голову ломал, что не так)